# $x^{13}+x+90$ is divisible by $x^2-x+a$ $(a\in\mathbb N)$. Find $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

> Question: $x^{13}+x+90$ is divisible by $x^2-x+a$ $(a\in\mathbb N)$. Find $a$.

What I did was:
\begin{align}
&x^{13}+x+90 = Q(x)(x^2-x+a)\\
&\text{Let $t$ be one of roots of }x^2-x+a=0\\
&t^2=t-a\\
&t^4=(t-a)^2=t^2-2at+a^2=(1-2a)t+a(a-1)\\
\\
&t^8=((1-2a)t+a(a-1))^2=(1-2a)^2t^2+2(1-2a)a(a-1)t+a^2(1-a)^2\\
&=(1-2a)^2(t-a)+2(1-2a)a(a-1)t+a^2(1-a)^2\\
&=(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))t+a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2\\
\\
&t^{12}={(1-2a)t+a(a-1)}{(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))t+a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2}\\
&=(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))t^2\\
&+ (a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2))t\\
&+ a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)\\
&=(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))(t-a)\\
&+(a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)²^2))t\\
&+ a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)\\
&=\left((1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2)\right)t\\
&+ a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)-a(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))\\\\
&t^{13}=((1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2))t^2\\
&+ (a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)-a(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1)))t\\
&=((1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2))(t-a)\\
&+ (a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)-a(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1)))t\\
&=((1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2)+a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)-a(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1)))t\\
&-a((1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2))\\
&=-t-90\\\\
&(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))+a(a-1)(1-2a)((1-2a)+2a(a-1))\\
&+(1-2a)(a^2(1-a)^2-a(1-2a)^2)\\
&+a^2(a-1)(a(1-a)^2-(1-2a)^2)-a(1-2a)^2((1-2a)+2a(a-1))\\&=-1\\
\\&\text{with an aid of Wlofram Alpha,}\\
&(a-2)(a^5-19a^4+32a^3-20a^2+5a-1)=0\\
&\therefore a=2
\end{align}

Is there a smarter way to get to the answer? Thanks.

(*) Any solution is welcomed, but this question was given to high school students who didn't learn calculus.

Comment: I'd imagine that using a division table would make life much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $x = 0$ hence $a \mid 90$

Set $x = 1$ hence $a \mid 92$

Find gcd of $90,92$. This is $2$, which means $a$ can be $1$ or $2$

Finally (credit to @fleablood) set $x = -1$. Note that $a+2$ has to divide $88$, so $a = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, but just one more question - how can we say that $Q(x)$ has all integer coefficients (not rational)?

Comment: @KayK. Why is that relevant?

Comment: Polynomial divisibility between two polynomials with integer coefficients (like in this case) is a very strong condition. If met, it means that no matter what value you set for $x$, the value of one polynomial will be divisible by the value of the other. You don't actually need to consider the coefficients of $Q(x)$ (which is why I never bothered to introduce this in my answer).

Comment: Okay. Thanks...

Comment: Still one more question: is the last line true? an odd number can still divide an even number.

Comment: "The only odd number that can divide an even number is 1"  Um, so 7 does not divide 14?

Comment: @fleablood Brainfart. Deleted. Writing new comment

Comment: If $x = -1 $ we have $a+2$ divides $88$ and $4|88$ but $3\not | 88$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks $x=-1$ gives a neater solution.

Comment: Actually, when we say "a polynomial divides another" does that mean the polynomials have integer coefficients or just rationals?  We have (x^2 - x + a)Q(x) = x^13 + x + 90 so if x = -1 we have $(a+2)Q(-1) = 88$ but can Q(-1) have a value of k/3? and does $aQ(1) = 92$ and $aQ(0) = 92$ mean thatn $Q(1)$ and $Q(0)$ must be integers?

Comment: @fleablood I'm beginning to think that we need the condition that the quotient must have integer coefficients (to allow the "smart" solution). Do you agree?

Comment: I think that may be part of the definition "divides" and for many texts it is implied in the word "polynomial"  (After all polynomial with rational coefficients q_i = m_i/n_i will have the exact same roots or lack thereof of the poly with integral coeficients m_i.lcm(m_j)/n_i).  If we allow rational coefficients then this is the same as solving for x^2 - x +a divides integer poly Kx^13 +Kx + 90K. Which if a ne 2 requires assumptions about K.  eg if a ne 2 then 2|K.  If a = 1 then 3|K and for all n^2+n + 1 divide K(x^13+x+90) which is no doubt impossible but we can do it in any *finite* number.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint:** Set $x=0$ then $a$ must divide $90$. Also setting $x=1$ shows that $a$ must divide $92$; so $a$ must divide the difference $2$.

The reason this works is because $x^2-x+a = x(x-1)+a$ so it is natural to find conditions on $a$ by setting $x=0,1$ so the first term drops out.

Comment: You must've beaten me by seconds! :)

Comment: This proves that $a$ is divisible by 2. But we still have to prove that $a=2$ is a solution and $a=-2$ and $\pm1$ are not.

Comment: @CYKwong Thanks, but $a\in\mathbb N$ was given in the condition.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that $a=1$ is not a solution (just realised it myself). But negative numbers are excluded by the $a$ is natural condition.

Comment: @CYKwong - that's why it's a **hint**! But anyway note that if $a$ is $\leq 0$ then $x^2 - x + a$ has two roots whilst $x^{13} + x  + 90$ has everywhere positive derivative. So we must have $a > 0$. Then we need only check between $a=1,2$.
Edit: well turns out the question makes this analysis redundant...

Comment: Now Deepak's solution is complete

Comment: One more question - how can we say that $Q(x)$ has all integer coefficients (not rational)?

Comment: @KayK. I'm not sure what you mean. Using your notation we have $0^{13} + 0 + 90 = 90 = Q(0)a$ and $1^{13} + 1 + 90=2=Q(1)a$. Regardless of what $Q$ has as coefficients we get that $a|90$ and $a|92$.

Comment: My question is how can we say $Q(0)$ and $Q(1)$ are integers..

Comment: If they aren't then $x^2-x+a$ doesn't divide $x^{13} + x + 90$. As you would have then have just demonstrated a value of $x$ such that your quadratic doesn't divide your other polynomial - in particular their quotient is some non-integer.

Comment: In other words, by definition a polynomial, by definition is assumed to mean one with integer coefficients?  $(2x + 6)(3x + 1/2) = 6x^2 + 19x + 3$ but we do not say $(2x + 6)|6x^2 + 19x + 3$?  Or do we?  It's a very important question. ...  Of course we'd never question that irrational coefficients aren't allowed...